# "Evaluate Expression" in IntelliJ throwing NoSuchMethodError for created stream

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nosuchmethoderror

During debugging in IntelliJ IDEA's Evaluate Expression window I obtain big collection of elements from database.

```
dao.getAll(Product.class);
```

This is returning `List<Product>`.  I want to filter this collection and find some specific items in them by using Java 8 Stream API.

```
dao.getAll(Product.class).stream()
        .filter(Product::isActive)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However I am getting `NoSuchMethodError` even if the method is present on given class.

[image: NoSuchMethodError when debugging]

When a `List<Product>` is created in code and not in Evaluate Expression window it is working. It doesn't matter which entity is used and which method is called. It is always behaving the same.

Is this expected behaviour for such ad-hoc created streams and is there a workaround?

EDIT:
It is not obvious what method is not found from the exception and its stacktrace.
Exception message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: a.b.MyClass.access$000(La/b/MyClass;)La/b/MySuperClass;
```

Stacktrace only leads to a place in code where my breakpoint is.
As I said above it doesn't matter which method on which entity is called. When everything including `dao.getAll(Product.class)` is called from Expression Evaluation window I am always getting this error. When  `dao.getAll(Product.class)` list is created in class file and stream is obtained and filtered in Expression Evaluation windows, it works.
Hope it make sense.

Comment: please specify what method is not found, it should be in the exception description

Comment: Please file a bug on debugger subsystem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA